# JAXB binding to override or remove XMLSchemaType xs:token

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am generating model classes from an xsd using the maven jaxb2 plugin. The xsd specifies certain elements with type=xs:token as follows:

```
<xs:element name="medium_text" type="xs:token"/>
```

This results in the following annotations being added to the field in the generated model:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name="token")
protected String medium_text;
```

The problem is the CollapsedStringAdapter removes new lines etc (which is the correct behaviour for xs:token) but I want to avoid this.

How can remove the xs:token type from the element or change it to xs:string using JAXB bindings? The easy solution is to remove the type from the xsd but is it possible using bindings without modifying the xsd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following in your binding file.

```xml
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation = "schema.xsd">
   <jxb:bindings node = "//xs:element[@name='medium_text']">
             <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.String"/> 
   </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

This results in the following:

```java
@XmlElement(name = "mid_text", required = true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "token")
protected String midText;
```

Adapter1 however is harmless and does not change the string value.

Also if you want to do this to all your `tokens` you can add a `globalBinding`

```xml
  <jxb:globalBindings>
            <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.String"
                xmlType="xs:token" />
  </jxb:globalBindings>
```